# Review count bug?

Tags: support

I see this on my upper bar:
[image: Top bar snippet]

But this is the number of edits in my queue:
[image: Suggested Edits snippet]

Is this a bug?  Going through the edits does not get rid of this and there are not 675 items in my other review queues, even as a total sum.

Comment: Here the reason http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#230726

Answer (score 2):

675 is the total review items. It's the sum of pending tasks review under all the queues: Close votes, First Posts, Low quality posts, Late Answers, Suggested Edits and Reopen Votes. Note that it also shows all the tasks you already completed, since it's for all users.

Comment: Isn't this counter-intuitive?  The indicator should be for things related to each person's review queue, not all the items that need review that you might have already skipped or done.  Otherwise, it makes people who have already cleared out their review queues think there's 600+ things for them to look at.

Comment: @ThomasW. that's the tradeoff. [Apparently having one counter for each was too wasteful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment758002_230726) The other alternative is not having one at all :(.